# Cake pattern and types

Tags: scala, types, cake-pattern

How can `def someA` (in `trait B`) use `trait A` with the same `C#MyType` as in `B` ? (Then `A#MyType =:= B#MyType`)

```
trait C {
  type MyType
}


trait A {
  self: C =>
  def doSomething(s: MyType) { println(s.toString)}
}

trait B {
  self: C =>  

  def someA: A
  def myType: MyType

  def action = someA.doSomething(myType)
}

// Mix part

case class Ahoy(value: String)

trait ConcreteC extends C {  
  type MyType = Ahoy
}


class PieceOfCake extends B with ConcreteC {
  val someA = new A with ConcreteC
  val myType = Ahoy("MyType")

}
```

It doesn't compile : type mismatch;

```
[error]  found   : B.this.MyType
[error]  required: _1.MyType where val _1: A
[error]   def action = someA.doSomething(myType))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare `doSomething` and `myType` to use the path independent version of `MyType`, `SomeType#MyType`:

```
trait SomeType {
  type MyType
}


trait A {
  self: SomeType =>
  def doSomething(s: SomeType#MyType) { println(s.toString)}
}

trait B {
  self: SomeType =>  

  def someA: A
  def myType: SomeType#MyType

  def action = someA.doSomething(myType)
}
```

Comment: Ok, it compiles, but you cannot mix a more specific SomeType with B.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't do that, since path-independent types are just that - if A<>B then A#T is strictly different from B#T (i.e. A#T will *never* be =:= B#T).

That being said, it's safe to cast, so you can always do something like `someA.doSomething(myType.asInstanceOf[someA#MyType])`. Ugly but works.

Comment: It doesn't work ? I mean you cannot cast on an unstable identifier.